# How do you test a has_many :through association using fixtures in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tdd, minitest, fixtures

I'm trying to set up an "[omakase](https://rubyonrails.org/doctrine/#omakase)" testing environment in Rails, which means minitest with fixtures, and I'm struggling to set up test fixtures for a `has_many :through` association. The [rails API says](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0.3.2/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html) that, "ActiveRecord reflects on the fixture's model class and discovers the has_and_belongs_to_many associations."

Because there is no specific documentation about fixtures for a `has_many :through` association, I was expecting that my fixtures might work the same as a HABTM relationship like this:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :project_categories
  has_many :categories, through: :project_categories
end

class ProjectCategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :project
end


class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :project_categories
  has_many :projects, through: :project_categories
end
```

test/fixtures:

```
project_one:
  title: Project One
  categories: category_a, category_b

category_a:
  name: Category A

category_b:
  name: Category B
```

So, in order to write a controller or system test that uses fixtures to test creating a new Project, do I need to set up also set up a `projects_categories.yml` fixture for the join table? Or, do I need to reference `project_one` in both of my categories fixtures? Or do I need to specify the association on all three—both the Project and Categories fixtures as well as a fixture for the join table?

I can't get my tests to pass if I only reference the categories from within the project fixture.

What is the "vanilla" rails way to do this with minitest and fixtures?

Comment: Create a bunch of join record fixtures. Encounter x number of bugs. Pull out some hair and switch to factories.

Comment: I really wish there was a more widely used "middle ground" between factories and fixtures because yeah factories are way easier but they're also _way_ slower

Comment: https://rubygems.org/gems/fixture_factory tries to be the 'middle ground'.

Comment: I appreciate that sentiment and have only used factories in the past. As I was saying, trying to do "omakase" rails with this and was wondering if there was something I'm missing other than, "Create a bunch of join record fixtures. Encounter x number of bugs". I thought there might be a better way. Definitely seems like this section of the rails API docs are a little vague.